# Cannot figure out how to use MODULO/MODULUS function in Caché SQL

Tags: sql, modulo, intersystems-cache

[Here is the documentation.](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_mod)

I'm using [DB Visualizer Pro](http://www.dbvis.com/) 9.2.6

I've tried multiple variants including the following

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName WHERE {ID MOD(5,3)}
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName WHERE ID MOD(5,3)
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName WHERE ID MOD 5 = 3
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName WHERE ID % 5 = 3
```

In all honesty the documentation makes no sense to me anyway...  Is "fn" field name?  I assume it's a function but then what field are they selecting?  It's just confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the [examples](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_mod#RSQL_C46152) that `fn` should be included, within the curly brackets:

> The following example shows the remainder returned by MOD.
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT {fn MOD(5,3)} AS Remainder
> FROM Sample.Person
> ```
>
> returns 2
>
> The following example shows the remainder returned by MOD with a negative dividend.
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT {fn MOD(-5,3)} AS Remainder
> FROM Sample.Person
> ```
>
> returns 1

If you check out another function, like [`ROUND`](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_round#RSQL_C47218) they use the same syntax (among others).

So in your case, maybe something like (assuming you want records satisfying `5 % ID == 3`)

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tableName WHERE {fn MOD(ID,5)} = 3
```

Confusing? Yes.

Comment: Well I didn't get an execution error, which is exciting!  It's been running for 45 minutes so I'll let you know how it goes in a couple days :D

Comment: You had the parameters switched around.  The following query gives me every 3rd row: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE {fn MOD(ID,3)} = 0`

Answer (score 1):

There is also a binary operator for modulo: #

http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_langelements#GSQL_langelements_ops_math

Comment: The familiar operator for modulo, %, was probably not used due to its significance in Cache-specific naming rules.